How do the Valence Bond Theory and Molecular Orbital Theory describe the same wavefunction
How do valence bond theory and molecular orbital theory describe the same wavefunction despite one having localized electrons in a bond overlap and one having wave superimposition forming delocalized molecular orbitals. Some explain it using the fact VBT measures wavefunction of different resonance structures but concept of resonance structure is inaccurate making the VBT seem inaccurate.
I know at high level and in true form especially using mathematics and wavefunctions, VBT and MOT essentially compliment each other and are the same

This question is similar to: What is actually the difference between valence bond theory and molecular orbital theory?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Mithoron My question is connecting and showing similarities between the theories not asking the difference. In my question, I am asking about a similarity and how VBT at highest level is same as MOT but using differences as an example. In the question you recommended, it is asking straight up about the differences. I am also talking about how despite saying different thingw, they connect and use same wavefunction which is not relayed to question given

A second that this is different and should not be closed, as you can't preemptively vote to reopen. The question here is about how, in the limit, VBT and MOT should result in identical wavefunctions. The linked question is about how the structure of the two theories differ.

Let's first remind ourselves of the problem that both Valence Bond Theory (VBT) and Molecular Orbital Theory (MOT) are trying to solve. It is the many-body non-relativistic electronic Schrödinger equation within the Born-Oppenheimer equation for the chemical system of interest:
$$\hat{H}\Psi=E\Psi$$
where $\hat{H}$ is the electronic Hamiltonian, $\Psi$ (what we really want) is the many-body, fully correlated electronic wavefunction and $E$ is the associated Eigenvalue/Energy.
Note the important words "many-body". This wavefunction is not the orbitals that we are introduced to early in our Chemistry career, it is the full, non-separable, correlated many body wavefunction which is a function of the position and spin coordinates of all the electrons. We can't talk about one electron at a time here, it's all or nothing.
And I could stop there. Both theories solve the same problem with, in the limit, no approximations, so they both get the same answer. End of story. But that's not especially informative, so let's take one or two more steps to see where the formulations start to diverge to see both how they differ and, in fact, how they are both in some ways really the same.
What do we know about the many-body electronic wavefunction? Well in principle not a lot except that because electrons are Fermions by the Pauli principle it must by antisymmetric with respect to exchange of electronic coordinates:$$
  \Psi({\bf{r_1}} ,{\bf{r_2}},...,{\bf{r_i}},...{\bf{r_j}},...,{\bf{r_N}})=
- \Psi({\bf{r_1}} ,{\bf{r_2}},...,{\bf{r_j}},...{\bf{r_i}},...,{\bf{r_N}})
$$
As such both VBT and MOT expand the many-body wavefunction in Slater determinants ensuring that the Pauli principle is obeyed due to the basic mathematical properties of determinants. Thus, for the moment, let us write
$$
\Psi=\sum_i c_i D_i
$$
where $D_i$ is one of these yet to be discussed determinants and $c_i$ is a coefficient which will be found by ensuring the resulting $\Psi$ is a solution to the above eigenvalue equation - in other words given a set of $D_i$ the problem is now to determine the corresponding $c_i$ and that gives us the exact, many body, fully correlated electronic wavefunction (in the Born-Oppenheminer approximation at the non-relativistic limit...).
So we now have to define the $\{D_i\}$. And it is here that VBT and MOT begin to differ in formulation - Valence Bond theory, in its purest form, takes determinants defined with respect to atomic orbitals, while Molecular orbital theory uses determinants derived from molecular orbitals, which I will define later on (and remember this is our first use of orbitals)
So what are these determinants? Well I'm not great at MathsJax so I'm going to steal a picture from here (which is well worth a read in itself, much more detail than I will ever provide):

So each term in the sum is a NxN determinant, where N is the number of electrons in the system. Each row of the determinant corresponds to a different electron. As swapping rows of a determinant changes the sign of the determinant this ensures the Pauli principle is obeyed. Also note if two rows or columns are identical the determinant is zero - this is the Pauli exclusion principle. The columns correspond to which spin orbitals we have decided to occupy in the particular term in the summation. A spin orbital is describes the behaviour of a single electron, and is a function of the spatial and spin coordinates of that electron alone. What we will have is a basis of many spin orbitals (their choice to be discussed), in principle many more than the number of electrons, and each term in the summation above corresponds to occupying a different selection of these spin orbitals. The calculation then becomes determining the weight of each of these occupation patterns in the summation.
In the purest form of VBT we choose the spin orbitals to be the atomic orbitals of the participating atoms. For instance if we look at $\ce{H_2}$ within a pure VBT framework we could, labelling the atoms 1 and 2, take the spin orbitals in our basis to consist of:

the up   spin atomic 1s orbital of atom 1
the down spin atomic 1s orbital of atom 1
the up   spin atomic 1s orbital of atom 2
the down spin atomic 1s orbital of atom 2

So we have 2 electrons and 4 basis functions. We then form every possible 2x2 determinant by choosing in turn every possible pair of basis functions, in effect occupying the chosen basis functions with the electrons - so we would form 2x2 determinants from

Spin orbitals 1 and 2 above
Spin orbitals 1 and 3
Spin orbitals 1 and 4
Spin orbitals 2 and 3
Spin orbitals 2 and 4
Spin orbitals 3 and 4

And we then put these 6 determinants in the above sum. And finally plug it all into the eigenvalue equation to find the $c_i$ and hence the many body, fully correlated electronic wavefunction (in the Born-Oppenheminer approximation at the non-relativistic limit...).
But not exact. We have made an approximation. A basis set of just 4 1s spin orbitals in not nearly flexible enough to describe the exact many body wave function. We have truncated our basis. To get a better description we need to include more basis functions. In pure VBT for the $\ce{ H_2}$ problem we might include the 2s and 2p functions, and occupying them into our summation and sum as above. And then we might add the n=3 atomic functions and so on to get even greater accuracy. And in the limit of a very large basis set (assuming certain properties of the basis set which I don't feel qualified to discuss) we will get the exact answer. But note that the number of determinants in our sum increases very rapidly - it is a combinatorial problem, given $N$ electrons and $N_b$ basis functions the number of determinants we in principle need to consider is
$$
{{N_b}!}\over{{N!}{(N-{N_b})!}}
$$
As a result inclusion of just the 2s and 2p atomic orbitals already gives us 66 determinants we need to at least consider - some we might decide a priori are going to contribute very little, but we at least need to think about them. Thus an accurate calculation for even small molecules rapidly becomes very expensive.
While this expense not really relevant to this question I'm going to use this as a motivation to look at Molecular Orbital Theory. Above we chose atomic orbitals as our basis. But this is purely a choice. We can make many other choices, and indeed what is to say that a basis derived from isolated atoms is going to be particularly good in molecules? So can we do some relatively cheap calculation to get, in some sense, a good basis, and then use that basis of spin orbitals in place of the the atomic orbitals above? A really good basis would be one in which we could neglect a huge number of the determinants. In fact a perfect basis would be one that only needs one determinant in the expansion. Can we find such a basis?
In general no. But we could ask "if I approximate the sum by a single term, just one determinant, can I find what basis I should choose to give the best approximation to the many body, fully correlated electronic wavefunction (in the Born-Oppenheminer approximation at the non-relativistic limit...)?". And if I define best as "gives the lowest total energy" the answer is "yes" - this is Hartree-Fock (HF) theory.
So in purest Molecular orbital theory we first solve a problem to generate the molecular spin orbitals, typically using Hartree-Fock theory, and then, if that is not sufficiently accurate for our purposes, proceed as above in VBT by selecting (some of) the HF spin orbitals as out basis, forming the expansion in determinants, and solving the for the $c_i$ as above. In MOT land this is known as Configuration interaction. And one would hope that as the molecular orbitals are particularly adapted to this particular molecule that a comparatively small number of determinants are required - so we hope, and I stress hope, that making the spin orbitals more flexible has made our problem more tractable.
Now as an aside as it's not strictly required for this it's probably worth saying a few words about Hartree-Fock theory and how it is commonly implemented as the language here often (to my mind) gets misused, or to some extent is inherently confusing. Firstly I've heard HF described as MO theory. It's not, it is part of MO theory, full MO theory requires configuration interaction. As such the HF wavefunction will almost always be different from the VBT wavefunction, but as HF is not all of MOT this is not a problem. I only mention this as I suspect occasionally this confusion of what the MOT wavefunction really is has caused people to think that there is an inherent difference between the two approaches. There isn't, in the limit MOT and VBT give the same answer.
Secondly we need a way to express the MOs as found by Hartree-Fock theory. Confusion alert! For this we use a basis, but this is a different basis from that used to construct the Slater determinants - we first construct a the MOs using some kind of basis (Gaussian type orbitals, plane waves and grids are common), and then use those MOs that we have constructed as a basis for the expansion of the many body wavefunction in terms of determinants. These bases are different things!
That's where I'm going to finish, at least for the moment, except to note that in reality the two methods I've described above are end points of a spectrum, and there is a whole range of methods in between. Modern VBT doesn't use pure, fixed, atomic functions but adds flexibility to its basis - so moving in the direction of MOT, the Coulson-Fischer method is an early step in this direction. Modern VBT implementations also do not, and indeed can not due to computational limitations, consider every single determinant except in very small cases. This is again a move toward MO theory where neglecting determinants is common. From the MO end I chose (that word again) to find the best single determinant to approximate the exact wavefunction. As we know the wavefunction is inherently multi-determinantal why not use a small number to generate the spin orbital basis? This is the Multi-configurational self-consistent field method, a clear step towards Valence Bond Theory - and in fact is mathematically extremely similar to one of the modern methods in the VBT school, Generalized valence bond.
Its also well worth looking at the question and answer linked in the comments, What is actually the difference between valence bond theory and molecular orbital theory? . One might say while I've provided a top down view, that presents the bottom up approach.
But that's enough - I am not an expert on VBT or post-Hartree fock methods, so I'll stop there.

I know, from some paper I read tons of months ago, that the relation between MVB and MO theory is essentially a Unitary Transformation, will you also cover this in the answer? Literature is a bit fragmented on the matter.

To be honest I am writing this answer to clarify my own thoughts on VBT (I am certainly not an expert!) - if I can see an obvious relationship I will, but otherwise not. Though it does seem fairly obvious that some kind of basis-set transformation will relate the two I can't see why it should be unitary; indeed given AOs are non-orthogonal and MOs are orthogonal off the top of my head I would have thought a non-unitary similarity transform is appropriate.

That was what I was thinking too, but I can't shake off my mind this article i read, I will check if I still have a copy and maybe write an answer too if I find it.

Actually if you express the MOs in the basis of the atomic functions used for the spin orbitals there may well be a unitary transformation between the two. But I would need to write down the maths before I was totally convinced

Found the article! There is indeed an argument just like the one you were proposing, I'll write down the math if I feel like it this evening!

Okay, I found the article discussed in the comments between Ian Bush and me. I also feel quite silly for not noticing earlier that this is almost trivial, considering canonical methods in quantum chemistry like CASSCF.
Basically, the relationship between localized and delocalized orbitals, and thus between "VB-like" and canonical MO orbitals, is governed by a unitary transformation. While MO orbitals obtained through HF methods are suitable for most "coarse" estimations of molecular properties, as shown by Hiberty and Braïda, if we apply a suitable unitary transformation to the molecular spin-orbitals involved in constructing Slater determinants, we can derive an equivalent set of localized orbitals that yield the exact same observables as the original MO set.

[...] it is well known[25 in Hiberty et al.] that replacing two orbitals by their sum and difference, or more generally making any unitary transformations of the orbitals, in a Slater determinant keeps its total value rigorously unchanged and hence leaves the corresponding many-electron wave function invariant, yielding the same energy, electronic density, and molecular properties as the original one based on CMOs. If the unitary transformations are performed so as to comply with a criterion of minimal repulsion between electron pairs, the so-transformed orbitals appear as localized MOs (LMOs), known also as localized bond orbitals (LBOs).

In their paper, which I find really clear even for experimentalists, they proceed to show the equivalence of both VB and MO approaches in different classical problems that historically made MO widely appreciated and VB taken as imprecise, addressing why, in the end, they both are equivalent.

So what you are saying is that You can replace Canonical Molecular orbitals with localized bond orbitals and it will yield same energy, electron density and molecular properties. If that is true, then what about benzene and nitrate - are these also going to be localized considering how often and with evidence how they are presented with delocalized systems. Also could one MO be more delocalized than another

The MOs are not unique; they simply form a basis for the subspace that describes the occupied states. At 0K any unitary transformation that does not mix in functions from outside that subspace leaves quantities such as the total energy or charge density unchanged

Yeah, Ian already said it, but be careful to put a LOT of emphasis on the o K requirement. When you start to average on occupied states, things get much less obvious (althought very interesting).

To put it another way all ground state properties can be expressed in terms of the Density matrix, and the density matrix is invariant WRT rotations within the occupied manifold. In many ways it is not the evecs we should be thinking in terms of, but the density matrix.

I agree that this the more general way to go. Actually the concept of density matrix greatly simplifies understanding, in my opinion. Also, density matrices are incredibly useful to talk about ensemble operators, I feel like any theoretical chemistry course should feature at least their introduction.
