I don't understand the difference between Valence Bond Theory and Molecular Orbital Theory
What does it mean that VBT is localized and MOT is delocalized?
"Unlike valence bond theory, which uses hybrid orbitals that are assigned to one specific atom, MO theory uses the combination of atomic orbitals to yield molecular orbitals that are delocalized over the entire molecule rather than being localized on its constituent atoms." I found this explanation but it still confuses me because doesn't VBT utilize wave functions (orbitals) which would explain that electrons are delocalized? So then how are their hybrid orbitals delocalized?
A simple explanation would do because I'm studying Gen Chem as a freshman right now and this topic is really confusing me. Thank you.

This question is similar to: What is actually the difference between valence bond theory and molecular orbital theory?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40626/hybrid-orbitals-forming-molecular-orbitals

Closely related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/184615/how-do-the-valence-bond-theory-and-molecular-orbital-theory-describe-the-same-wa
